# React Native Android App "Could not connect to development server."

Tags: android, react-native

My app that works fine on my machine and simulator crashes when I try to open the release I uploaded to the play store. Here is the error message I am receiving via the crash report on the developer console:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not connect to development server.
>   Try the following to fix the issue:
>   Ensure that the packager server is running
>   Ensure that your device/emulator is connected to your machine and has USB debugging enabled - run 'adb devices' to see a list of connected devices
>   If you're on a physical device connected to the same machine, run 'adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081' to forward requests from your device
>   If your device is on the same Wi-Fi network, set 'Debug server host & port for device' in 'Dev settings' to y
>       at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManagerImpl.createReactContext(ReactInstanceManagerImpl.java:911)
>       at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManagerImpl.access$700(ReactInstanceManagerImpl.java:100)
>       at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManagerImpl$ReactContextInitAsyncTask.doInBackground(ReactInstanceManagerImpl.java:197)
>       at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManagerImpl$ReactContextInitAsyncTask.doInBackground(ReactInstanceManagerImpl.java:180)
>       at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>       at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
>   Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not connect to development server.
>   Try the following to fix the issue:
>   Ensure that the packager server is running
>   Ensure that your device/emulator is connected to your machine and has USB debugging enabled - run 'adb devices' to see a list of connected devices
>   If you're on a physical device connected to the same machine, run 'adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081' to forward requests from your device
>   If your device is on the same Wi-Fi network, set 'Debug server host & port for device' in 'Dev settings' to y
>       at com.facebook.react.common.futures.SimpleSettableFuture.get(SimpleSettableFuture.java:68)
>       at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManagerImpl.createReactContext(ReactInstanceManagerImpl.java:882)
>       ... 9 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not connect to development server.
>   Try the following to fix the issue:
>   Ensure that the packager server is running
>   Ensure that your device/emulator is connected to your machine and has USB debugging enabled - run 'adb devices' to see a list of connected devices
>   If you're on a physical device connected to the same machine, run 'adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081' to forward requests from your device
>   If your device is on the same Wi-Fi network, set 'Debug server host & port for device' in 'Dev settings' to y
>       at com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactBridge.loadScriptFromAssets(Native Method)
>       at com.facebook.react.bridge.JSBundleLoader$1.loadScript(JSBundleLoader.java:32)
>       at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.runJSBundle(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:149)
>       at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManagerImpl$4.call(ReactInstanceManagerImpl.java:902)
>       at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManagerImpl$4.call(ReactInstanceManagerImpl.java:883)
>       at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$1.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:73)
>       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>       at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31)
>       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
>       at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:193)
>       ... 1 more

Can anybody help me with this? I am happy to to provide more info if needed.

Comment: Did you ever find the solution, Thomas? I think [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42768354/executionexception-in-createreactcontext-could-no-connect-to-develpment-s) is about the same problem, judging from the stack trace you posted.