# React-Native "Could no connect to development server" in createReactContext()

Tags: react-native

My Android react-native app is crashing with an `ExecutionException`.

> "Could not connect to development server."

The method that is crashing is `ReactInstanceManagerImpl.createReactContext()`.

But this is **not the normal error** as this screenshot shows:

[image]

Logcat shows me this stacktrace:

```
Exception in native call from JS
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException:
 Could not connect to development server.
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManagerImpl.createReactContext(ReactInstanceManagerImpl.java:860)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManagerImpl.access$700(ReactInstanceManagerImpl.java:98)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManagerImpl$ReactContextInitAsyncTask.doInBackground(ReactInstanceManagerImpl.java:194)
        ...
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException:
        at com.facebook.react.common.futures.SimpleSettableFuture.get(SimpleSettableFuture.java:68)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManagerImpl.createReactContext(ReactInstanceManagerImpl.java:831)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactBridge.loadScriptFromFile(Native Method)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JSBundleLoader$2.loadScript(JSBundleLoader.java:58)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.runJSBundle(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:148)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManagerImpl$4.call(ReactInstanceManagerImpl.java:851)
        ...
```

This suggests that the server has sent the javascript code back to the device and the `ReactBridge.loadScriptFromFile()` somehow can't handle the bundle.

---

Points to clarify:

- this happens on emulator & device (connected via USB)
- this happens on Linux (Mint) & Windows (8.1)
- I did run `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081` as per the normal advice
- I have run `react-native start` and the packager/server is running
- the device DOES connect to the development server, as this is logged in the packager window
- the URL that the device hits does return data, as can be seen if copied into the browser address bar

---

**How is this different** from the *normal* "Could not connect..." message?

Here is a screenshot of what happens when the server is legitimately not running:

[image]

The differences include:

- no `ExecutionException` or `RuntimeException` before the error message
- further clarity providing the URL that was called on the server
- error comes from `DevServerHelper.onFailure()`

Logcat shows the stacktrace to be quite different in this *normal* expected case:

```
Unable to download JS bundle
com.facebook.react.devsupport.DebugServerException:
 Could not connect to development server.
        at com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevServerHelper$1.onFailure(DevServerHelper.java:196)
        at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:140)
        at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: I found 2 possibly related posts without much more useful information: [Thomas' one here from 2016](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38470417/react-native-android-app-could-not-connect-to-development-server) and [Clu's one from just the other day](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42233514/could-not-connect-to-development-server-running-react-native-even-though-develop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have been caused by not having Windows Build Tools correctly installed. This broke the `node-gyp` commands required by my project.

Following the steps on [the node-gyp page](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp) got my machine set up correctly.

After a new build I got this error once, and then it disappeared with the project building and running correctly.